# Profiling Cache hit rate of a function of C program

Tags: c, linux, perf, papi, intel-pmu

I want to get cache hit rate for a specific function of a C/C++ program (**foo**) running on a Linux machine. I am using gcc and no compiler optimization. With *perf* I can get hit rates for the entire program using the following command.

> perf stat -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-dcache-stores,L1-dcache-store-misses ./a.out

But I am interested in the kernel **foo** only.

Is there a way to get hit rates only for **foo** using *perf* or any other tool?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define NI 192
#define NJ NI

#ifndef DATA_TYPE
    #define DATA_TYPE float
#endif


static 
void* xmalloc(size_t num)
{
    void * nnew = NULL;
    int ret = posix_memalign (&nnew, 32, num);
    if(!nnew || ret)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not allocate Memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return nnew;
}

void* alloc_data(unsigned long long int n, int elt_size)
{
    size_t val = n;
    val *= elt_size;
    void* ret = xmalloc(val);
    return ret;
}


/* Array initialization. */
static
void init_array(int ni, int nj,
        DATA_TYPE A[NI][NJ],
        DATA_TYPE R[NJ][NJ],
        DATA_TYPE Q[NI][NJ])
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < nj; j++) {
      A[i][j] = ((DATA_TYPE) i*j) / ni;
      Q[i][j] = ((DATA_TYPE) i*(j+1)) / nj;
    }
  for (i = 0; i < nj; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < nj; j++)
      R[i][j] = ((DATA_TYPE) i*(j+2)) / nj;
}


/* Main computational kernel.*/

static
void foo(int ni, int nj,
        DATA_TYPE A[NI][NJ],
        DATA_TYPE R[NJ][NJ],
        DATA_TYPE Q[NI][NJ])
{
  int i, j, k;

  DATA_TYPE nrm;
  for (k = 0; k < nj; k++)
  {
    nrm = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
      nrm += A[i][k] * A[i][k];
    R[k][k] = sqrt(nrm);
    for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
      Q[i][k] = A[i][k] / R[k][k];
    for (j = k + 1; j < nj; j++)
    {
      R[k][j] = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
        R[k][j] += Q[i][k] * A[i][j];
      for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
        A[i][j] = A[i][j] - Q[i][k] * R[k][j];
    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  /* Retrieve problem size. */
  int ni = NI;
  int nj = NJ;

  /* Variable declaration/allocation. */
  DATA_TYPE (*A)[NI][NJ];
  DATA_TYPE (*R)[NI][NJ];
  DATA_TYPE (*Q)[NI][NJ];

  A = ((DATA_TYPE (*)[NI][NJ])(alloc_data((NI*NJ), (sizeof(DATA_TYPE)))));
  R = ((DATA_TYPE (*)[NI][NJ])(alloc_data((NI*NJ), (sizeof(DATA_TYPE)))));
  Q = ((DATA_TYPE (*)[NI][NJ])(alloc_data((NI*NJ), (sizeof(DATA_TYPE)))));
  
/* Initialize array(s). */
  init_array (ni, nj,
          (*A),
          (*R),
          (*Q));


  /* Run kernel. */
  foo (ni, nj, *A, *R, *Q);

  /* Be clean. */
  free((void *)A);
  free((void *)R);
  free((void *)Q);

  return 0;
}
```

Output of lscpu command is:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15 
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel 
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5960X CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              2
CPU max MHz:           3500.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
```

Comment: Write a program which only runs `foo()` and measure it?

Comment: What your want is a caliper measurement: a "start counter" before calling foo() and a "stop counter" upon the end of foo(). To make it, you will need to instrument the code and rebuild it. The ability to get the counters depends on the processor architecture and its PMU. The way to get the counters is vendor specific. That is why libraries like papi are useful as they support multiple processor/PMU architectures transparently. Why were you not able to use papi ?

Comment: @hyde: That would include counts for dynamic-linking, and for the alloc / initialize part.  You can count only user-space by using `perf stat --all-user` (or with older `perf`, with `event:u,event:u,...`)  So yeah you could just time the whole program if you can repeat `foo` a lot of times to drown out the background noise of the init work; if it can be run multiple times without redoing its init.  But that may be impractical if you want to run `foo` with a large array that includes a lot of init time.

Comment: @PeterCordes Could use static linking. Could precalculate the array.

Comment: @hyde, yes, but with large static data the first run of `foo()` will hit page faults, instead of reading recently-written memory that's probably hot in the TLBs, and very likely at least won't page-fault, so some HW prefetching and OoO exec across page boundaries will be available even if it's just looping over a big contiguous array.  If it's a pointer-based data structure (like a tree), mmaping with `MAP_FIXED` is plausible but a big pain to create data for, and to use.  And not viable if `foo` involves `free()` on any of the initialized data.

Comment: @Richard K. I basically tried PAPI for this. 

Tried to use this formula L1-D-Cache hit rate = 1 - PAPI_L1_DCM/(PAPI_LD_INS+PAPI_SR_INS)

Comment: But this is returning me error code -8(Event exists, but cannot be counted due to counter resource limitations) when I try to add those events using **PAPI_add_event** function. It fails when I try to add three events. If I add only two events, it works fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure. Depends on the exact purpose, whether that matters much or not. On a general purpose multi-user multi-tasking OS, there's going to be a lot of noise on a shared resource like CPU cache anyway. High process priority might be useful too.

Comment: @AtanuBarai: When you use `perf` from the command line, does it let you use more than 2 events (other than instructions or cycles which have "fixed" counters) without having to multiplex the counters?  (extra column of % of time this counter was active).  Have you disabled the NMI-watchdog that uses up one programmable counter?

Comment: @Peter Cordes No perf doesn't. I guess there are not enough counters in the CPU for that. So, one solution might be add only two events at a time, get counter values and in the next run add other counter and get the counter value. Disabling NMI-watchdog is a good idea. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: @AtanuBarai: What is your CPU architecture ? If it is Intel, can you edit your question and add the result of the "cpuid -1" command ? The latter is verbose, just share the header (CPU identification) and the PMU part (Architecture Performance Monitoring Features entries).

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed: it is clear...

Comment: @RachidK.I added the output of lscpu command here.

Comment: With cpuid, you would get information about the PMU as well (especially the number of counters in the sections "Architecture Performance Monitoring Features"

Comment: According to [Intel documentation](https://www.intel.fr/content/www/fr/fr/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.html): Intel Core i7 processor family supports architectural performance monitoring provides four general-purpose performance counters (IA32_PMC0, IA32_PMC1, IA32_PMC2, IA32_PMC3) and three fixed-function performance counters (IA32_FIXED_CTR0, IA32_FIXED_CTR1, IA32_FIXED_CTR2) in the processor core.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Likwid](https://hpc.fau.de/research/tools/likwid/) and its [Marker-API](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid/wiki/TutorialMarkerC). It makes it very easy to instrument certain regions of your code. You can use the predefined *performance group* **ICACHE** on the haswell architecture for the L1 cache miss rate or define your own performance group for the L1 hit rate.

```
#include likwid.h
LIKWID_MARKER_INIT;
LIKWID_MARKER_START("region foo");

foo();

LIKWID_MARKER_STOP("region foo");
LIKWID_MARKER_CLOSE;
```

run application with:

`./likwid-perfctr -g ICACHE -m <your application>`

Make sure to compile with `-DLIKWID-PERFMON` and add the Likwid include and library path and link the Likwid library: `-L$LIKWID_LIB -I$LIKWID_INCLUDE -llikwid`.
Everything is documented very well on their [github wiki](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid/wiki)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [gprof(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html). It won't measure cache hit rate (this has no sense, since some calls to `foo` could be inlined, once [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) is invoked with optimizations enabled).

You could use [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) in your code. See also [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

You might compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -g -pg` then use `libbacktrace` (like [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) are doing) inside it, and later [gprof(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html) with [gdb(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html).

With efforts (so read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)) you might use [setitimer(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) with [sigaction(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and/or [profil(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/profil.3.html).

Consider also *generating* some C code (e.g. using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) and/or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) in your own C code generator) and see [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065). J.Pitrat's book [*Artificial Beings: the Conscience of a Conscious Machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) (ISBN-13: 978-1848211018) could be inspirational. You may want to generate some C code for extra instrumentation.

You might generate some code in a plugin (e.g. with [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)...) at runtime, then [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) it. Read more about [*partial evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) and see my [`manydl.c`](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) example, and more seriously the source code of [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) or of [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/).

You could write your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to automatically generate some measurements, in a more clever way than what the `-pg` option of GCC is doing. Your GCC plugin would transform (at the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) level) most function calls to something more complex making some benchmarking (this is how `-pg` works inside GCC, and you might study the source code of GCC). Try compiling your `foo.c` as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -pg -S -fverbose-asm foo.c` and look into the generated `foo.s`, perhaps adding more [optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), or [static analysis](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) or [instrumentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) options.

You could be interested in recent papers of [ACM SIGPLAN](https://sigplan.org/).

At last, benchmarking a C program compiled *without* optimizations makes no sense. Consider instead compiling and linking your program with at least `gcc -flto -O2 -Wall`

Within your `foo`, you might use cleverly [clock_gettime(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) to measure CPU time.

And if performance is very important and if you are allowed to spend weeks of work to improve it, you might consider using [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (or perhaps [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)) to compute your kernel on a powerful GPGPU. Of course, you need dedicated hardware. Otherwise, consider using [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) or [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC) (or perhaps [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)). Some recent GCC compilers (at least [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in October 2020) could support these. Of course, **read documentation on [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't see it's relevant with the question.

Comment: We don't understand your question. Consider improving it with some [mre] coded in C. And you should use [profil(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/profil.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `L1-dcache-store-misses` is not supported on your processor. `perf stat` will tell you that in the output.

`perf stat` doesn't let you profile only selected regions of code. To do that, you have to manually instrument the code so that the specified events are controlled around the regions of interest as desired.

It's not possible to count the events `L1-dcache-loads`, `L1-dcache-load-misses`, and `L1-dcache-stores` without multiplexing on your processor (Haswell). They're mapped to the native events `MEM_UOPS_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS`, `L1D.REPLACEMENT`, and `MEM_UOPS_RETIRED.ALL_STORES`, respectively. Each of these events can only be counted the first four general-purpose counters. In addition, there is a bug that is not documented in the specification update document of the i7-5960X, but does exist in the i7-5960X (it's documented in the spec update documents of other Haswell processors and processors of some other microarchitectures). This bug is handled differently in different versions of perf. Starting with kernel version 4.1-rc7, if one of the events that is affected by the bug is enabled on a logical core and if hyperthreading is enabled at boot-time, a logical core can only use up to two of its four general-purpose counters. The `MEM_UOPS_RETIRED.*` events are among the ones affected by the bug. One thing you can do is disable hyperthreading.

It's important to understand what kind of "cache hit rate" can be measured with these events. You probably don't want to measure something that doesn't make sense. One ratio that may make sense is `L1-dcache-load-misses` / (`L1-dcache-loads` + `L1-dcache-stores`), which represents the number of L1D replacements (lines filled in the cache that cause others to be evicted) for any reason divided by the number of retired load and store uops. Not all misses cause replacements and a significant portion of all misses may hit in the LFBs, which also don't cause replacements. Also not all replacement are caused by accesses from uops that end up retiring.